# How to extract sub strings in lua

Tags: design-patterns, lua, substring, capture

I have a string `"[testid-1] is locked out /  / Subject: /  Account Domain: NM /"` and I need to extract `"testid-1"` within the square braces and domain `"NM"` out of the string using Lua script. I am trying to use the below code with no luck, I have also tried escaping `[`.

`aname=string.match(a,'[(.*)]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured that the escape character in lua is %. This code works fine:

```
aname=string.match(a,'%[(.*)%]')
adomain=string.match(a,'.*Account Domain: (%a+)')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single call:

```
aname, adomain = a:match('%[(.*)%].*Account Domain:%s*(.-)%s*/')
```